# Two Column HTML table using Rails 3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table

I seriously searched for 3 days on this topic, but I am unable to find anything that can help me solve my issue.

I have a table that prints out Kanban cards for the factory I work in, but the Avery sheet where I need to print them is 2 col by 3 rows, and my table is displaying 3 col X 2 rows.

### card 1|card 2|card 3

### card 4|card 5|card 6

I need this layout to be 2 col by X rows.

### card 1|card 2

### card 3|card 4

### card 5|card 6

This is my Rails view:

```
    <% count = @card.start%>
<% @card.finish.times do %>
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" class="table">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="part_no_card_no" class="all">
            <%= @card.part_no %>
            &nbsp
            &nbsp
            <%= count %> /
            <%= @card.finish %>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= image_tag "#{@card.part_no}" + "-" + "#{count}" + "-" + "#{@card.finish}" + ".png" %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= @card.description %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= @card.from_loc %>
            -
            <%= @card.to_loc %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cantidad en Bin: <%= @card.bin_qty %>  EA
        </td>
    </tr>

        </td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
</table>
<% count += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

I hope someone could provide some direction on this task.

Comment: I am not a ruby developer, but I can tell the there is a mistake on line no: 4 `<tr>` should not be there and at the end on line no: 37-40 there are `</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>`
remove that as well. These are HTML mistakes. I hope this will help you a little. Thanks

Comment: It's a little hard to follow. From what I can tell, all of your rows have exactly one column. How are you seeing 3?

Comment: this is more of a HTML thing.  To have two columns in a row, keep two <td>'s inside a <tr></tr> tag eg. <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>

Comment: You want to be static table or dynamic table? If you want to have some dynamic table see my answer. Hope can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is more of a HTML thing.  To have two columns in a row, keep two 's inside a  tag eg.

e.g for 2 columns

```
<tr>
 <td>col-1</td>
 <td>col-2</td>
</tr>
```

for 4 columns

```
<tr>
 <td>col-1</td>
 <td>col-2</td>
 <td>col-3</td>
 <td>col-4</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi Bala, thanks to all for responding by the way. So then I would have to add a condition to determine which data goes on the left and which on the right using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm not quite understand about your card system and it's attribute, since you just show some simple layout but your `view` looks more advance about it. So I give you an example about my code, and I will edit whenever it's needed.

I have a table named `user_menus` and I want to show it like: (`[]` mean `checkbox`)

```
[] Products     [] Suppliers
[] Categories   [] Units
```

I use [`.in_groups_of()`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) for it.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <% @user_menus.in_groups_of(2, false) do |user_menu_array| %>
      <tr>
        <% for user_menu in user_menu_array %>
        <td>
          <label class="checkbox">
          <%= check_box_tag "user_group[user_menu_ids][]", user_menu.id, @user_group.user_menus.include?(user_menu), :checked => true %>
          <%= user_menu.name %>
          </label>
        </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

With this code, I can produced that easily.

Comment: With my solution you not needed to create your table manual anymore. This way was more DRY and simple that what I found since my `user_menus` was dynamic. If your `card` was dynamic also, I think this solution can provide you greater result lesser effort. Hope can help